# PowerShell Hide-WUUpdate to Hide specific KB update

Tags: powershell

Trying to hide a specific KB update with `Hide-WUUpdate` Here is what I am trying

```
Hide-WUUpdate –KBArticleID “KB4034664” -ComputerName PCNAME –Confirm:$false
```

I get the following output

```
WARNING: You haven't privileges to make this. Try start an eleated Windows PowerShell console
```

I have tried with an "Elevated Powershell" Any ideas?

After running this as suggested

`Hide-WUUpdate –KBArticleID “KB4034664” -ComputerName PCNAME –Confirm:$false -Debuger`

I got the following output.

```
DEBUG: STAGE 0: Prepare environment 
DEBUG: Check if ComputerName in set
DEBUG: STAGE 1: Get updates list
DEBUG: Create Microsoft.Update.Session object for PCNAME
DEBUG: Create Microsoft.Update.Session.Searcher object for PCNAME
DEBUG: Set source of updates to default (for PCNAME) Windows Update
DEBUG: Set pre search criteria: IsInstalled = 0
DEBUG: Search criteria is: IsInstalled = 0
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: Dell Inc. - Bus Controllers and Ports, Display - Dell 1907FP(Analog)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: LSI - Storage - Dell SAS 6/iR Integrated Workstation Controller
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2574819)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2592687)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2830477)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3080079)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3102429)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: 2017-08 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 for x64-based System
s (KB4034664)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: Convert size
DEBUG: Convert KBArticleIDs
WARNING: You haven't privileges to make this. Try start an eleated Windows PowerShell console.
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: August, 2017 Preview of Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.
6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7 on Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4035036)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: 2017-08 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 7 for x64-based Syst
ems (KB4034670)
DEBUG: Set post search criteria: KBArticleIDs = 'KB4034664'
DEBUG: UpdateAccess: false'
```

Powershell remote IS enabled on the remote computer.

Comment: Are you admin on the box?

Comment: I am Admin in the entire domain. I have tried running powershell as admin as well

Comment: What is 'PCNAME'? I reckon that is a remote computer?

Comment: Yes, PCNAME is the remote PC I would like to run this on. PCNAME is NOT the real name.

Comment: OK. Please execute this and show the output: `Hide-WUUpdate –KBArticleID “KB4034664” -ComputerName PCNAME –Confirm:$false -Debuger`

Comment: Reply won't let me post all of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, just edit your original question with the output.

Comment: Ok, do you have powershell remoting enabled on your remote computer? https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing all the information, I believe you **do not have the required permissions/access** to perform this operation remotely.

Your script is a 3rd party script. The debug info is not specially informative. All that can be said is that the script fails on setting the hidden property on the update.

The best shot you have is to **enable Powershell Remoting** to make sure you have the remote access you need to run this. Nevertheless there is a chance that it still may not work due to some Microsoft security restrictions. In that case I'd advise you to install and configure **Microsoft Windows Server Update Services** which will enable you to perform this task.

Comment: I will accept this as the best answer. When I run this on the local machine it works just fine.

`Hide-WUUpdate –KBArticleID “KB4034664”  –Confirm:$false`

I have made sure the Powershell Remoting is enabled but it still fails. WSUS isn't an option right now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming [this](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/1.6.1.1/Content/Hide-WUUpdate.ps1) is the script you're using, it looks like the error message is from line 550.  That warning message is from an error trap that's concealing the actual error.  I'd recommend changing the code to something like this:

```
If ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($Computer, "$StatusName $($Update.Title)?")) {
    Try {
        $Update.IsHidden = $HideStatus
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Warning "You haven't privileges to make this. Try start an eleated Windows PowerShell console."
        throw ($_)
    }

} #$pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($Computer,"Hide $($Update.Title)?")
```

Now you should be able to see the actual error message instead of the friendly, non-informative warning the script author decided you should get.

Comment: This is useful, but it is not an answer to the question. This belongs in a comment.

Comment: Not running that script just running a simple one line `Hide-WUUpdate –KBArticleID “KB4034664” -ComputerName PCNAME –Confirm:$false`

Comment: @Eric `Hide-WUUpdate` is not a built-in command, and it's not compiled.  You've either installed it from [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc) or [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/1.6.1.1). 
 You can find out where it's installed by running `Get-Module -Name 'PSWindowsUpdate' -ListAvailable | Select-Object -Property Path`.  You'll find `Hide-WUUpdate.ps1` in that folder.

Comment: In installed it from the Windows Update Module.

Comment: @Eric That in no way means that it's not still a script.

Comment: You should actually try doing the modification that @BaconBits suggests. It *might* give you some additional info.